# Writting SQL command to traverse Vertex on Edges conditions

Tags: java, orientdb

Imagine the following schema
[image]

Let's say each edge is of type "manage" with an attribute "permissions" set to "rw" or "r-" or "--" and each vertex is of type Account.

Here, Account 3 is not able to write in Account 5, but since Account 1 is able to write in Account 3, i want Account 1 to be able to write in Account 5.

What I want to do is a Java function able to check if a connected user (account 1) is able to write in an account given as parameter.
So I have to check if the first edge on the way to go to the to-be-modified-account has a write permission.
(Hope that's clear)

I think it would work to have a recursive function, but i'd like to find a way to do it with SQL command.

I was thinking to use the "$depth" keyword something like

```
select from (traverse out('manage') from #1 while $depth <= 1) where @class='Account'
```

I need to had something like "where permissions='rw'" somewhere, but I could not find how to get the Edge instance with this.

And once the condition would have been implemented for the first outgoing edge, i would need to continue traversing the edges, without this condition anymore.

May be it is not possible to do, please let me know

And tell me if it is not clear enough

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create class Account extends V

create class Manage extends E
create property Manage.permissions string


create vertex Account set name = 'dummy'                    #12:0

create vertex Account set name = 'account1'                 #12:1
create vertex Account set name = 'account2'                 #12:2
create vertex Account set name = 'account3'                 #12:3
create vertex Account set name = 'account4'                 #12:4
create vertex Account set name = 'account5'                 #12:5


create edge Manage from #12:1 to #12:2 set permissions = "r-"
create edge Manage from #12:2 to #12:4 set permissions = "rw"
create edge Manage from #12:1 to #12:3 set permissions = "rw"
create edge Manage from #12:3 to #12:5 set permissions = "r-"
```

I believe this is the situation described above. You can:

```
traverse out('Manage') 
from ( 
  select expand(outE('Manage')[permissions='rw'].in) from #12:1 
)
```

This returns all the accounts **#12:1** has **rw** permission.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but problem with this command is that it's only returning Account3 here, I'd like a command returning Account3 and Account5. I mean: all the Accounts below when the first edge contain 'rw'

Comment: Did you try the sequence of steps in my answer? It should return __account3__ and __account5__.

Comment: Ok sorry I did a mistake when creating my edges, that's working, thanks a lot !